# Java - Scanner comment skip

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My task in this lab is to accept multiple input file and the format is similar in all of them except that some files have comments and I want to skip the comments lines. For example:

Input file:

```
Input file 1

#comment: next 5 lines are are for to be placed in an array
blah 1
blah 2
blah 3 
blah 4
blah 5

#comment: next 2 line are to be placed in a different array
blah 1 
blah 2

#end of input file 1
```

---

What I tried doing was I used 2 while loops (I can post my code if needed). I did the following

```
while(s.hasNext()) {
    while(!(s.nextLine().startWith("#")) {
        //for loop used to put in array
        array[i] = s.nextLine();
    }
}
```

I feel like this should work but it does not. What am I doing incorrect. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You are invoking `nextLine` more than once within the loop.
2. Your second `while` loop will fail if there is no next line.

Try modifying code as follows:

```
int i = 0;
while(s.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = s.nextLine();
    if(!line.startWith("#")) {
          array[i++] = line;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are losing the good lines, should be:

```
String line;
while(!(line = s.nextLine()).startWith("#")) {
    array[i] = line;
}
```

Comment: @ThomasMueller - I didn't I left only the essence of the code in purpose.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is it will be reading only alternate lines in the array because the nextLine() method will be called twice (once in the while test expression and the second time in the while body) before a line is read as opposed to once... what binyamin suggested would work for you.